# Nuxt.Js redirect parent page to index

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I have pages folder structure as follow:

```
--pages
  --projects
    --slug.vue
  --index.vue
```

When I go to the "/projects/something" URL it's work fine, but when I go to the "/project" URL I would like see (main page) index.vue.  How can I do that?

Comment: are you using dynamic routing? or static?

Comment: Dynamic routing

Answer (score 0):

you should use like this way

```
--pages
  --projects
    --_slug.vue
    --index.vue
```

hope it will sove the problem. you can read more from [here](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/routing-dynamic-pages/)